# gdal2tiles not referencing properly

Tags: openlayers-2, gdal, leaflet

I'm trying to overlay satellite images in a web page, images are properly georeferenced.

[image: Example of image]

When I use gdal2tiles by default it throws an error:

```
gdal2tiles.py --zoom 0-5 --s_srs EPSG:4326 20173481715B02G16.tif dist/

ERROR 6: EPSG PCS/GCS code 900913 not found in EPSG support files.  Is this a valid
EPSG coordinate system?
ERROR 6: No translation for an empty SRS to PROJ.4 format is known.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 2278, in <module>
    gdal2tiles.process()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 482, in process
    self.open_input()
  File "/usr/bin/gdal2tiles.py", line 856, in open_input
    self.out_ds.SetMetadataItem('NODATA_VALUES','%i %i %i' % (self.in_nodata[0],self.in_nodata[1],self.in_nodata[2]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

However if I use a profile such as **raster** or **geodetic** it works fine but when I overlay that layer over an OpenStreetMap layer, using leaflets or openlayers the result its a mess, the layer goes to Antarctica.

```
gdal2tiles.py --zoom 0-5 --profile geodetic --no-kml 20173481715B02G16.tif dist/
gdal2tiles.py --zoom 0-5 --profile raster --no-kml 20173481715B02G16.tif dist/
```

[image: Image not working]

This example it's using the **raster** profile, with **geodetic** the result it's pretty similar.

I did try to force projection with **--s_srs EPSG:4326** parameter, change the projection in openlayers but nothing seams to work.

What am I doing wrong or how can I fix this?

Comment: What is your GDAL version from `gdalinfo --version`?

Comment: You can also have a try with just a current version of gdal2tiles.py https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py that is using the correct EPSG:3857 code for Web Mercator.

Comment: this is the version ```GDAL 1.11.3, released 2015/09/16```

The tiff image is in EPSG:4326
```GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]```

Comment: The reported error is "PCS/GCS code 900913 not found in EPSG support files". Use newer script that does not use that fake code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out that I was using and old version of the script. With the new version all problems are gone.

Thanks @user30184.